# ListView id not valid

Tags: android, listview

i've got a problem with an activity with root element ListView. I've followed  [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/carlosefonseca/5337861) to load items into listview and all work. But i've tried to change the id of the listview and now, when the activity is loading, i receive this problem:

> Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is "android.R.id.list"

I retried to change id to "list" but i've got the same problem. I don't have problems in compiling but in run-time. This is the code of the activity when i load the listview.

```
public class StartActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    //Section inflating
    adapter.addSection(getString(R.string.equationmenu), new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] {getString(R.string.eq1title), getString(R.string.eq2title), getString(R.string.eqfractitle)}));

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

SectionedAdapter adapter = new SectionedAdapter() {
    protected View getHeaderView(String caption, int index,
                                 View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView result = (TextView) convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            result = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.header, null);
        }

        result.setText(caption);

        return (result);
    }
};
}
```

And this is the xml of the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />
```

Anyone can help me? :)

Comment: use `android:id="@android:id/list"` instead `android:id="@+id/list"` for ListView id in xml

Comment: i tried, but eclipse give a problem: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/list')

Comment: what kind of problem?

Comment: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@id/list')

Comment: and when you get this error how does your xml look like?

Comment: but in the R class i found the id: public static final int list=0x7f07000f;

Comment: android:id="@id/list"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you extend from ListActivity you have to let the id of the ListView in your xml

> (android:id="@android:id/list")

If you want to change the Id or use more than one ListView in your Activity than you have to 
extend from Activity and inflate a ListView yourself..

For example like below:

> ListView list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList1);
>   list1.setAdapter(...);
>
> ListView list2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList2);
>   list2.setAdapter(...);